# New array, derived from another array of pointers to strings, just in a different order (in C)

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, iar

I'm after a little help with arrays and pointers if possible...

I have defined some const strings:

```
static const Int8U item1[] = {0x4D, 0x61, 0x72, 0x74, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x20, 0x4D, 0x43, 0x50, 0x37, 0x38, 0x31, 0x30, 0x00};
static const Int8U item2[] = {0x4D, 0x61, 0x74, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x20, 0x4D, 0x43, 0x50, 0x37, 0x38, 0x31, 0x30, 0x00};
static const Int8U item3[] = {0x4D, 0x61, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x20, 0x4D, 0x43, 0x50, 0x37, 0x38, 0x31, 0x30, 0x00};
```

I reference these strings in an array of pointers:

```
const Int8U* original_sequence[] =
{
    item1,
    item2,
    item3
}

#define SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_1 (0)
#define SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_2 (1)
#define SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_3 (2)
```

I can refer to any of the strings via something similar to:

```
original_sequence[SEQUENCE_ELEMENT1]
```

All good so far. However, there is another configuration which consists of the same items, just in a different order. Ideally, I would like to do this following, declared with global scope:

```
const CHAR *new_sequence[3] =
{
    original_sequence[SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_2],
    original_sequence[SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_1],
    original_sequence[SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_3]
};
```

However I get the error 'expression must have a constant value'. Please note that I cannot refer to the 'item1' etc directly, because the #defines are key in the identification.

I've also tried variants of this, like:

```
const CHAR **new_sequence[3] =
{
    (char**)original_sequence[SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_2].
    (char**)original_sequence[SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_1].
    (char**)original_sequence[SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_3]
};
```

Nothing seems to get me anywhere. I can't work out if I'm confusing myself with pointers, or if I'm falling foul of a compiler limitation? The thing that makes me think it's not a limitation is that if I was to reference the 'item1' strings directly in this new array I don't think there would be an issue.

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: You for some reason have `.` instead of `,` in several places. Are `array_one` and `array1` supposed to be the same thing?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've renamed some of the elements now to hopefully make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately what you are trying to do is not allowed in standard C language.

C17 draft explains that you cannot use value of object in address constant expression:

> ### 6.6 Constant expressions
>
> ...
>
> 9. An address constant is a null pointer, a pointer to an lvalue designating an object of static storage duration, or a pointer to a function designator; it shall be created explicitly using the unary `&` operator or an integer constant cast to pointer type, or implicitly by the use of an expression of array or function type. **The array-subscript `[]`** and member-access `.` and `->` operators, the address `&` and indirection `*` unary operators, and pointer casts **may be used in the creation of an address constant, but the value of an object shall not be accessed by use of these operators.**

Your variant almost works, but you need to add address of operator:

```
const CHAR **new_sequence[3] =
{
    (char**)&original_sequence[SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_2],
    (char**)&original_sequence[SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_1],
    (char**)&original_sequence[SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_3]
};
```

However it has a downside that you need additional dereference on use:

```
*new_sequence[index]
```

I would simply put SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_* constants in plain integer array and use function to hide details of access, and call this function whenever new_sequence element is needed:

```
uint8_t new_sequence[] = {
    SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_2,
    SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_1,
    SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_3
};

char * get_new_sequence_text(int index) {
    return (char*)original_sequence[new_sequence[index]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message already tells you, what's wrong. The initialization elements must be constant values, which is not the case, when you derive the values from another variable/array. See also [Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/initialization#Notes)

> When initializing an object of *static or thread-local storage duration*, every expression in the initializer must be a *constant expression* or string literal.

So the only way to initialize it is by using constant values, e.g.

```
const Int8U *new_sequence[3] =
{
    item2,
    item1,
    item3
};
```

or do it inside a function

```
void func()
{
    const Int8U *new_sequence[3] =
    {
        original_sequence[SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_2],
        original_sequence[SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_1],
        original_sequence[SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_3]
    };
}
```

or do it dynamically in code

```
new_sequence[0] = original_sequence[SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_2];
new_sequence[1] = original_sequence[SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_1];
new_sequence[2] = original_sequence[SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_3];
```

or have some other indirect scheme

```
int new_sequence_index[] =
{
    SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_2,
    SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_1,
    SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_3
};
```

and do the accesses via `original_sequence[new_sequence_index[0]]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Practically, there are two problems:

- Your data sets have different length, meaning you have to use pointers and sizes instead of just creating a big multi-dimensional array of everything (which would be simpler and more effective).
- You can't refer to things that aren't constant expressions from within an initializer list of an object with static storage duration ("global" etc). Addresses of other variables can be used, but not the values of those variables.

To work around this, you could in theory create some icky pointer-to-pointer tables, but the syntax will quickly turn messy. A less obscure alternative might be to create one single data set, then create tables of indices instead of tables of pointers.

For example you could do this:

```
#define ITEM1 0x4D, 0x61, 0x72, 0x74, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x20, 0x4D, 0x43, 0x50, 0x37, 0x38, 0x31, 0x30, 0x00
#define ITEM2 0x4D, 0x61, 0x74, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x20, 0x4D, 0x43, 0x50, 0x37, 0x38, 0x31, 0x30, 0x00
#define ITEM3 0x4D, 0x61, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x20, 0x4D, 0x43, 0x50, 0x37, 0x38, 0x31, 0x30, 0x00

static const uint8_t* const data[3] =
{
  (const uint8_t[]) { ITEM1 },
  (const uint8_t[]) { ITEM2 },
  (const uint8_t[]) { ITEM3 },
};
```

(I got rid of icky home-made types in favour of standard C stdint.h, as everyone should.)

This creates a read-only pointer table which points to 3 read-only arrays. Each array gets the same scope as the pointer table itself. You could do this to create multiple tables with different order, but that creates a lot of overhead data. So instead maybe consider this approach:

```
enum
{
  SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_1,
  SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_2,
  SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_3,
};

static const size_t original_sequence[3] =
{
  SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_1,
  SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_2,
  SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_3,
};

static const size_t new_sequence[3] =
{
  SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_2,
  SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_1,
  SEQUENCE_ELEMENT_3,
};
```

You'd now have one set of data which you can access in the following manner:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<3; i++)
{
  for(size_t j=0; i<something; j++)
  {
    uint8_t a = data[ original_sequence[i] ][j];
    ...
  }
}
```

The missing piece of the puzzle is however where the individual sizes of each item collection are stored. I assume these are strings, in which case `something` above is the string length, which can be pre-calculated at compile-time.